# using namespace used as type C++

Tags: c++

I found a piece of code that uses the following statement:

```
using flags = std::ios_base::fmtflags;
flags fl = std::ios_base::dec;
```

This is the first time that I encountered it. How can you use a namespace as a type.

Comment: It's not a namespace, its a *type alias*

Comment: `using namespace` and `using other_stuff` are different. You can read them as plain English to understand the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing [type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) with [`using` declerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations). Type aliasing behaves like a `typedef`, it defines another name for an existing type.
Your example is equivalent to the following :

```
typedef std::ios_base::fmtflags flags;
flags fl = std::ios_base::dec;
```

Comment: @SergeyA `using` can be templated.

Comment: Than it becomes alias template, not type alias.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody uses a namespace as a type in this snippet. `std::ios_base::fmtflags` is a type, not a namespace, and this `using flags = std::ios_base::fmtflags;` line just introduces an alias to it.